# How to change label value to be like password field value?

Tags: javascript, html, label

i'm having password like value to be set into label to be shown as ***(as per characters).

```
<label>password</label>
```

Output of this shown like below,because label value whatever it is.

```
password
```

**Expected result:**

`********`

In my case its should be converted like `********` (as per no of characters).

Am newbie to js. Any one suggest me key points to do this.

How to convert this to be number of * values as per characters?

Comment: Do you want to have an input that doesn't show what's in it, or an actual Lable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another simple solution :

```
<html>
<body>


<label id="passw">password</label>

<script>
var pass= document.getElementById("passw").innerHTML;
var char = pass.length;
var password ="";
for (i=0;i<char;i++)
{
password += "*";
}
document.getElementById("passw").innerHTML = password;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For pure Javascript with no jQuery you could use `split()` to transform string to array and then `map()` to modify each element based on condition.

```js
var label = document.getElementById('password');

let replaceAll = (str, chars = []) => {
  return str.split('')
  .map(c => c.trim() && !chars.includes(c) ? '*' : c)
  .join('');
}
  
label.innerHTML = replaceAll(label.textContent, '*');
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span>Field without formatting</span>
  <label id='standard'>password</label>
  <hr />
  <span>Field with formatting</span>
  <label id='password'>password</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant store ***** in a label and also a the value of the password, you can use a input with visibility: hidden like:

```
<input type="password" name="pwd" style="visibility: hidden"></input>
<label id="lblPwd"></label>
```

And treat it in javascript to show same value in the label.

Or you can use an input and set the css to show like a label:

```
<style type="text/css">

.label{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border:none;
}

</style>

<input type="password" class="label" disabled/>
```